# "Adding" inner products

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Is there a general rule to simplify things like $<x,y> - <x,z>$ or generally $<.,.> \pm <.,.>$

I cant find anything in my notes that talks about this.

Comment: Do you really mean for the first coordinate to be the same, or would $\langle a, b \rangle \pm \langle c, d \rangle$ be more representative of what you're interested in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition of bilinearity, $\langle x,y\rangle - \langle x,z\rangle = \langle x,y-z\rangle$.

On the other hand in general there is no formula for $\langle a,b\rangle \pm \langle c,d\rangle$.

Comment: On the bilinearity one you wrote, could you elaborate on why it is that please. Also what if it was +?

Comment: I don't know what your definition of "inner product" is, but in general it is defined as a symmetric "bilinear" map $V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ (I assume you work over $\mathbb{R}$ given the tags of the question). This means that by definition $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle y,x\rangle$, $\langle \lambda x,y\rangle = \lambda\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle x+y,z\rangle = \langle x,z\rangle + \langle y,z\rangle$. So in particular it also works with a $+$.

Comment: with the definition we are given, one of the properties is $<ax+by,z>=a<x,z>+b<y,z>$. So I am guessing this can also mean: $<x,ay+bz>=a<x,y>+b<x,z>$ right???

Comment: Yes, by symmetry this is equivalent.

Comment: Also, when we are working with real values only, we can always say $<x,y>=<y,x>$ right? And when it is complex, then $<x,y>=<\bar y, \bar x >$. Is this correct?

Comment: The english terminology on "inner products" is a bit fuzzy if you ask me, but you are thinking of hermitian products. in this case the correct formula is $\langle y,x\rangle = \overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$. The expression $\overline{x}$ if $x\in V$ is ill-defined. It only makes sense after a choice of basis, so it's a very bad notion that shouldn't be used in general.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar that I did while I was working on a problem to show the continuity of Inner products w.r.t ||.|| (the natural norm):
    Needed to show the difference between (un,vn) and (u,v) < e for all e>0, given that vn --> v and un -->u, both w.r.t ||.||

1. I expanding (un, vn) as (un-u, vn) + (u,vn) (something you can prove using the axioms of <.,.>)
2. Now that we have a common element "u" in the first position:
   (un, vn) - (u, v) = ((un-u, vn) + (u, vn)) - (u, v)
                 = (un-u, vn) + (u, vn-v)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Please consider using [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to type beautiful and beautifully formatted mathematical texts.